Prefixed indexes in Oracle
I know it is not logical to have 2 indexes when one is prefix of another one, I mean if I have following indexes:
create index ix_vch_plc on tb_voucher(fk_plc);
create index ix_vch_plc2 on tb_voucher(fk_plc, version)

the 2nd index can serve all queries which 1st one serves, so it is better to drop 1st index (as version is a number), to get less disk space usage, more efficient DMLs.
now my question is what about following indexes:
create index ix_vch_plc on tb_voucher(fk_plc)
create unique index ux_vch_plc on tb_voucher(fk_plc, case when fk_plc is not null then version end)

the 2nd index mandates uniqueness of (fk_plc, version) where fk_plc is not null, so it is essential on my database, but it seems the 1st one is still a prefix of 2nd one. And as Oracle does not put all-null tuples in index, both indexes will have same cardinality.
So my question is should I keep the first index? does 2nd index (which is more complex because of case expression) serve queries which 1st one serve?
